# Defining default @GeneratedValue Strategy for Symfony MakerBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-4.2

When using the MakerBundle in Symfony (4) to create new entity (`make:entity EntityName`), an id is generated by default with annotation (if annotations enabled) `@GeneratedValue`.

`@GeneratedValue` means `@GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`.

According to the [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys), the `AUTO` strategy is supposed to use **SERIAL** type for the id in PostgreSQL. But, I do not know why in my case, the `AUTO` strategy use SEQUENCE for the id.

Then, I can force it to use SERIAL by changing by hand into `@GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` which means using **SERIAL** type in PostgreSQL.

Is there any way to change the default @GeneratedValue annotation created by the MakerBundle for the new entities to be created with the `@GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could possibly do is [decorate](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) [`\Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Doctrine\EntityClassGenerator`](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Doctrine/EntityClassGenerator.php) which is registered as a service named [`maker.entity_class_generator` in `vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Resources/config/services.xml`](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/config/services.xml#L46) and override its `generateEntityClass` method to make a different call on the `Generator`'s `generateClass` method, specifically the file path could be changed there.

Seems like the file path there could be relative or absolute, so with some trial and error you could get it to output the annotation you want. The template that the maker bundle uses now is at [`vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Resources/skeleton/doctrine/Entity.tpl.php`](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/skeleton/doctrine/Entity.tpl.php), and it's pretty straightforward to modify.